# XSLT2.0: solution to take all nodes in one tag if parent is same

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

Hi I want to write xslt 2.0 solution for following example.

I want to take all the child elements inside one character untill the node is other character itself

Input xml

```
<para>
<character>
 <formatting>format</formatting>
</character>
<character>
 <formatting>format1</formatting
<formatting>format2</formatting
</character>
this is a text node
<character>
 <formatting>format3</formatting>
</character>
<character>
 <formatting>format7</formatting>
<formatting>format8</formatting>
</character>
</para>
```

Expected output

```
<para>
<character>

    <formatting>format</formatting>
    <formatting>format1</formatting>
    <formatting>format2</formatting>

</character>
this is a text node
<character>
<formatting>format3</formatting>
 <formatting>format7</formatting
<formatting>format8</formatting
</character>
</para>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `xsl:for-each-group` and group adjacent based on the name.

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<para>
    <character>
        <formatting>format</formatting>
    </character>
    <character>
        <formatting>format1</formatting>
        <formatting>format2</formatting>
    </character>
    this is a text node
    <character>
        <formatting>format3</formatting>
    </character>
    <character>
        <formatting>format7</formatting>
        <formatting>format8</formatting>
    </character>
</para>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="para">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="name()">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="current-group()[1][self::character]">
                        <character>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/node()"/>                            
                        </character>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>            
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<para>
   <character>
      <formatting>format</formatting>
      <formatting>format1</formatting>
      <formatting>format2</formatting>
   </character>
    this is a text node
    <character>
      <formatting>format3</formatting>
      <formatting>format7</formatting>
      <formatting>format8</formatting>
   </character>
</para>
```